# What is the structure of writing clara rules externally in an edn file (clojure)?

Tags: clojure, rules, clara-rule-engine

This is the structure that I found in cerner/clara-rules repo's test case:

```
(def external-rules "[{:name \"cold-query\", :params #{:?l}, :lhs [{:type clara.rules.testfacts.Temperature, :constraints [(< temperature 50) (= ?t temperature) (= ?l location)]}]}]")
```

I'm writting but in a `rules.edn` file. When required I read it and it to session with `mk-session`. In this Im able write basic rules and it is getting fired as required. But the issue is I want to take to next step where I want to access the facts in the session and modify it.
Let say there is a defrecord that is inserted as a fact after creating a session. And Im able to insert facts on :rhs with `insert!` but I need to know how to fetch the existing ones in the next chain of rules.

I tried binding the defrecord to variable as in the documentation of clara, in `defrule`. But unable to do so with similar constraints as in `defrule`  (`?td <- Temperature`) where Temperature is a defrecord in current session. I tried referring the defrecord as `clara.rules.testfacts.Temperature` and `clara.rules.testfacts.Temperature.` but it didn't work.

That is where Im not able to find the full structure of writing the defrule externally.

**UPDATE**
This is how I used it actually.

```
(defrecord User [user-id user-name])

(defrecord UserCriteria [#^ints ids])

(defn fetch-rules-from-file []
(edn/read-string (str "[" (slurp "rules.edn") "]")))

(defn run-rules []
 (let [res (-> (mk-session (fetch-rules-from-file))
                (insert (->User [:userfact1 :userfact2] )
                        (->UserCriteria (list nil)))
                (fire-rules))])
)
```

**rules.edn file**

```
{
:name "criteria-1", 
:lhs [{
      :type rules.rules.Users, 
      :constraints [conditions]}
      ] 
:rhs [(clara.rules/insert! (rules.rules.UserCriteria. [1])]
}
```

The above mentioned rules works, as it is doing the basic insertion with static data, but what I want to do is get the previous UserCriteria defrecord in the session and update the list.

```
{
:name "criteria-1", 
:lhs [{
      :type rules.rules.Users, 
      :constraints [conditions]}
      ] 
:rhs [(let [id (some-function-call)
            updated-criteria (conj (:id rules.rules.Segments.) id)]
           (clara.rules/insert! 
              (rules.rules.UserCriteria. updated-criteria))]
}
```

Also, I want to know how do we get the fact inserted into the session. Im able to get the defrecord from session using`:fact->explanations` key but its a map that is nested into levels of list.

```
(first (first (:fact->explanation session-data))
```

This is how the session data looks like:

```
{:fact->explanations {#rules.rules.UserCriteria{:id [1]} [:rule {fact }]} }
```

This is giving me the result though but would like to know if there is any better approach.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @cfrick I have updated it, could you check that?

Comment: I want to access the current session's fact in :rhs of the rule, how can I do that?
May binding the variable in :lhs and use that, but don't know how to bind that defrecord. It is possible in `defrule` thought as     `[?uc <- UserCriteria]`
then we can use `?uc` to get the current state of that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to figure out the structure of the defrule. You can write a `defrule` first and use `clojure.pprint/pprint` to get the structure for whichever working defrule you want to write in its meta form to a edn file.

```
(defrule rule1
 "Rule for Active User"
  [User (= is-active true)]
  [?u <- User]
  => 
  (println "Active User"))

(clojure.pprint/pprint rule1)
```

This would print the following:

```
{:ns-name rules.rules,
 :lhs [{:type rules.rules.Users,
        :constraints [= is-active true],
        }
        {:type rules.rules.Users,
         :constraints []
         :fact-binding :?u
         }],
 :rhs (do (println "Active User")),
 :name "rules.rules/rule1",
 :doc "Rule for Active User"
}
```